Camera Feed Only Shows a Square; Rest of the Screen is Black
I hope you're all doing well!
I'm working on a barcode scanner application using the react-native-vision-camera@4.3.2 library. However, I'm encountering an issue where the camera only displays a square in the center of the screen, while the rest of the screen remains black.
Here's a snippet of my code:
const BarcodeScanner: React.FC<Navigation> = props => {

   const device = useCameraDevice('back')
   const codeScanner = useCodeScanner({
        codeTypes: [
            'code-128'
            , 'code-39'
            , 'code-93'
            , 'codabar'
            , 'ean-13'
            , 'ean-8'
            , 'itf'
            , 'upc-e'
            , 'upc-a'
            , 'qr'
            , 'pdf-417'
            , 'aztec'
            , 'data-matrix'

        ],
        onCodeScanned: (codes: Code[], frame: CodeScannerFrame) => {
           //...
        }
    });


    return device !== null ? (
            <Camera
                style={StyleSheet.absoluteFill}
                device={device}
                isActive={true}
                codeScanner={codeScanner}
                torch={isFlashOn ? "on" : "off"}/>
    )
        : null
}

I've double-checked my setup, but I can't seem to figure out what's causing this problem. My React Native version is 0.73.6.
Has anyone faced a similar issue or could provide some guidance on how to resolve this? Any help would be greatly appreciated!
Thank you!

